# package keyval error: current slide undefined

Tags: beamer, errors, packages, xkeyval

I'm trying to prepare a presentation using latex but it gives an error:

> "package keyval error: current slide undefined.  See the keyval
>   package documentation for explanation.Type H  for immediate
>   help. ... l.50 \end{frame} [return] Try typing  to proceed. If
>   that doesn't work, type X  to quit."

This is how my presentation latex code looks like:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{default}

\usepackage{pgf,algorithm,algorithmic,amsbsy,amsmath,amssymb,epsfig,bbm,mathrsfs,mathdots, subfigure}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\newcommand{\beq}{\begin{equation}}
\newcommand{\eeq}{\end{equation}}
\newcommand{\beqn}{\begin{eqnarray}}
\newcommand{\eeqn}{\end{eqnarray}}
\newcommand{\ba}{\begin{array}}
\newcommand{\ea}{\end{array}}

\title{On Cooperative }
\author{K. } 
\institute{Department \\
University \\
}

\date{  \\ {\today}}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\hfill
\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}


\begin{document}

\AtBeginSection{}

\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Outline}
\fontsize{9}{4}\selectfont{}
\tableofcontents[currentslide]
\end{frame}
```

Any help, pls

Comment: Remove `[currentslide]` from `\tableofcontents`.

Comment: `\fontsize{9}{4}\selectfont{}` specifies text that is in a 9pt font on lines that are 4pt apart, do you intend that? (and don't load epsfig:-)

Comment: Unconnected to the question, but that attempt to make 'shortcuts' for the `align` environment will fail. Use the proper LaTeX environment syntax, making use of your editors automation features as appropriate.

Comment: David: Regarding font u r correct. I do not lead .eps files

Comment: Sigur:-> I removed but error is still there

Comment: besides removing `[currentslide]` also `\end{document}` is missing. With these two things, your example works.

Comment: Thanks for ur comments. Actually, \end{document} is there ... I have forgotten to include it in the above code... I could not figure out this error.... any kind of a help is highly appreciated ..

Comment: It is working once I comment currentslide ...... Sorry for the confusion.... Thank you very much

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved in the comments ...